# WPF C# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' After Changing ImageSource Several Times

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list view menu that will change the background image of a grid but after changing the image for about 5-6 times, the program freezes and when I closed the program the error was System.OutOfMemoryException. Here is the code I'm using.

```
 private void ListViewMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (((ListViewItem)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem).Name)
        {
            case "Ground":
                imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\1.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case "Second":
                imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\2.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case "Third":
                imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\3.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case "Fourth":
                imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\4.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case "Fifth":
                imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\5.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case "Sixth":
                imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\6.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case "Seventh":
                imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\7.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to dispose the previous `BitmapImage`

Comment: You can't explicitly dispose of a BitmapImage (it's not an IDisposable), but you can of course reuse them instead of creating new ones each time.

Comment: @Clemens how will I be able to do that?

Comment: Add seven BitmapImage fields to the class like `private BitmapImage image1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\1.png", UriKind.Relative));`. Then use them like `imageMap.Source = image1;`

Comment: Even better would be a single `Dictionary<string, ImageSource>` member. It would avoid the need for the switch statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System.GC;
...

private void ListViewMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    switch (((ListViewItem)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem).Name)
    {
        case "Ground":
            imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\1.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
        case "Second":
            imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\2.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
        case "Third":
            imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\3.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
        case "Fourth":
            imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\4.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
        case "Fifth":
            imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\5.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
        case "Sixth":
            imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\6.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
        case "Seventh":
            imageMap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\main\7.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: A horrible solution. You're usually doing things wrong when you need to explicitly call the garbage collector.